# How to randomize the same values in Hashmap in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, hashmap

```
 Map<Integer, BigDecimal> vendorRating = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> sortedList = new LinkedList<>();
```

vendorRating has values (11=>4,12=>3.5,13=>3,14=>3.5,15=>4,16=>5)

I want to sort the key based on value and shuffle the same value.

Output should be like [16,11,15,12,14,13], [16,15,11,14,12,13],[16,15,11,12,14,13], [16,11,15,14,12,13]

I have tried as below, this is working for sorting but i don't know i to shuffel the same value.

```
  vendorRating.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .forEachOrdered(
                x -> sortedList.addAll(Collections.singleton(x.getKey()))
        );
```

Comment: Why are `[16,15,11,12,14,13]` and `[16,11,15,14,12,13]` are not included in your output? And what if three or more keys share the same value?

Comment: Yeah, these can be include in output, i just put 2 output for reference. any no of keys can share the value, they need to be shuffle @Eritrean

Comment: Why do you `sortedList.addAll(Collections.singleton(x.getKey()))` instead of just `sortedList.add(x.getKey())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a map like:

```
Map<Integer, BigDecimal> vendorRating = Map.of( 11, BigDecimal.valueOf(4),
                                                12, BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5),
                                                13, BigDecimal.valueOf(3),
                                                14, BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5),
                                                15, BigDecimal.valueOf(4),
                                                16, BigDecimal.valueOf(5));
```

You first need a comparator to sort in descending order as desired:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, BigDecimal>> comp = Map.Entry.comparingByValue();
```

Using above comparator in a stream you can then use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group the entries having the same value to produce a `Map<BigDecimal,List<Integer>>`

```
Map<BigDecimal,List<Integer>> grouped =
            
    vendorRating.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(comp.reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, LinkedHashMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
    
    System.out.println(grouped);

//output: {5=[16], 4=[11, 15], 3.5=[12, 14], 3=[13]}
```

As you seem to only be interested in the keys of your original map and not the BigDecimal values I'll use below only the values of the above map `grouped.values()`, i.e `[[16], [11, 15], [12, 14], [13]]`

And here comes the intersting part. Now you need to geerate all permutations of each list which is not a trivial task but possible to write an algorithm by yourself to do so. But many libraries like Guava, Apache commons have already such functionalities. I recomend using a lib instead of implementing a permutation generating algorithm. I will use [combinatoricslib3](https://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib3) which I find very handy when working with streams.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.dpaukov</groupId>
   <artifactId>combinatoricslib3</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

As you can see the examples in the linked page above with combinatoricslib3 you can generate permutations very easily and the syntax is simple, Example to generate permutations of some strings

```
Generator.permutation("apple", "orange", "cherry")
   .simple()
   .stream()
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

//will output

```
[apple, orange, cherry]
[apple, cherry, orange]
[cherry, apple, orange]
[cherry, orange, apple]
[orange, cherry, apple]
[orange, apple, cherry]
```

Applied to your usecase, generating permutations of each sublist could look like

```
grouped.values().stream()
            .map(list -> Generator.permutation(list).simple().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

will give you :

```
[[16]]
[[15, 11], [11, 15]]
[[12, 14], [14, 12]]
[[13]]
```

which is close to your desired end result but not quite there. You need now to pick one element at a time from each sublist to get your end result, which is the same as producing the Cartesian Product of the lists. And luckily this is also possible with combinatoricslib3. But I am sure other libs like Guava have implementations for the same. Syntax is like above very simple. Look at the their examples if you need more info.

First storing the intermediate result in a list of lists:

```
List<List<List<Integer>>> perms = grouped.values().stream()
                                            .map(list -> Generator.permutation(list)
                                                    .simple().stream()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

//and generating the cartasian product

Generator.cartesianProduct(perms)
            .stream()
            .forEach(System.out::println);

//should produce something like:

[[16], [15, 11], [14, 12], [13]]
[[16], [15, 11], [12, 14], [13]]
[[16], [11, 15], [14, 12], [13]]
[[16], [11, 15], [12, 14], [13]]
```

Which is almost your end result. You need to only stream over the inner lists and flatmap to collect them in one list:

```
Generator.cartesianProduct(perms)
            .stream()
            .map(lili -> lili.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

will finaly get you to your destination:

```
[16, 15, 11, 14, 12, 13]
[16, 15, 11, 12, 14, 13]
[16, 11, 15, 14, 12, 13]
[16, 11, 15, 12, 14, 13]
```

I break the whole task in smaller steps in order to explain it easly. If you are not interested in storing intermadiate results but only in the final output you can inline the steps and make it in one go. A working demo:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.paukov.combinatorics3.Generator;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, BigDecimal> vendorRating = Map.of( 11, BigDecimal.valueOf(4),
                                                        12, BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5),
                                                        13, BigDecimal.valueOf(3),
                                                        14, BigDecimal.valueOf(3.5),
                                                        15, BigDecimal.valueOf(4),
                                                        16, BigDecimal.valueOf(5));

        Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, BigDecimal>> comp = Map.Entry.comparingByValue();
        
        List<List<Integer>> result =
        Generator.cartesianProduct(
                vendorRating.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .sorted(comp.reversed())
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, LinkedHashMap::new,
                                Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
                        .values().stream()
                        .map(list -> Generator.permutation(list).simple().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).stream()
                .map(lili -> lili.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        result.forEach(System.out::println);        
    }
}
```

output

```
[16, 15, 11, 14, 12, 13]
[16, 15, 11, 12, 14, 13]
[16, 11, 15, 14, 12, 13]
[16, 11, 15, 12, 14, 13]
```

The answer has become much longer than originally thought. Here is a potato for the long post

```
System.out.println("Potato");
```